# Using Firebase for notifications, getting `app instance has been unregistered`

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Trying to use Firebase for cross-platform mobile notifications. The client code to get a device token seems to work, as we can send notifications from the Firebase web console. But I cannot figure out how to send notifications from our server. We get the error: `app instance has been unregistered; code: registration-token-not-registered; details: Requested entity was not found` when calling `messagingClient.Send` in the following Go code snippet:

```
    ctx := r.Context()
    opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("serviceAccountKey.json")
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }

    // Obtain a messaging.Client from the App.
    messagingClient, err := app.Messaging(ctx)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }
    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    message := &messaging.Message{
      Notification: &messaging.Notification{
        Title: "Notification title",
        Body:  "Notification body",
      },
      Token: myDeviceToken,
    }

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    response, err := messagingClient.Send(ctx, message)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }
```

The credentials file that we're using is from the Firebase console, under Settings, Service Accounts, Firebase Admin SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation for FCM error codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin_sdk_error_reference), registration-token-not-registered means:

> The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid
>   registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons,
>   including:
>
> - The client app unregistered itself from FCM.
> - The client app was automatically unregistered. This can happen if the user uninstalls the application or, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback
>     Service reported the APNS token as invalid.
> - The registration token expired. For example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens or the APNS token may have expired for iOS
>     devices.
> - The client app was updated, but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
>
> For all these cases, remove this registration token and stop using it
>   to send messages.

Given that there are several possibilities here, it's not really possible for us to say which one it is.  If you need assistance troubleshooting with FCM, please [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) with exact steps anyone can take to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it worked to remove the notification permissions from the page and request them again, this caused a new token to be generated and it no longer gave that error.

I hope to help you